# IE7 Standalone to run on x64 Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, internet-explorer, compatibility, installer

Hello I just updated my Vista computer to have IE8. Well, now I would like to have the standalone version of IE7 also.(to test for browser compatibility while creating websites)

So I downloaded it from here http://tredosoft.com/IE7_standalone Well, the installer that they made gave me some error about a DLL procedure entry point. Downloading the actual IE installer directly(the 14M one) gave me a "Internet Explorer 7 is not compatible with this platform." This makes no sense because about 20 minutes ago I had a non-standalone version of internet explorer 7 running.

**How can I get IE7-Standalone to run on my x64 Vista machine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've thoroughly read the website that you've provided (I've seen it before.) you would know that it doesn't work on Vista or 7 yet. That project is a bit behind.

The "Internet Explorer 7 is not compatible with this platform."  is because it is an XP version (or older) of IE7. This is similar to copying the calculator program from Vista to XP or vice-versa. It's technically the same thing, but under the hood it's meant for two distinct OS's. Again, this has to do with the progress of that project.

Also, the Windows 7 XP Mode video explains that Using XP Mode is "the only way to run two versions of MS Office on the same machine." That would apply here as well - until that project that you mentioned is updated.

To answer your question: Use a virtual machine.

Comment: ugh.. well guess just have to setup that old machine thats not being used to run IE7 then..

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives come to mind:

[Expression Web SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en).

[Internet Explorer App Compat](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) images.

Both way easier than wandering down into DLL hell!  For your current issue you might just want to redownload the full IE8 package and get back to square one.

Comment: +1 just run XP or Vista with IE7 in MS VPC, it's free

Comment: Not if you don't have an unused license of XP

Comment: The XP license(s) come with the application compatibility image(s). They're time-locked so you periodically have to get updated ones.